# SQL Server Management Studio closes automatically

Tags: sql-server, ssms

suddenly My MSSQL Server Management Studio throw's error

> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)

Database successfully connecting but

> While opening **New Query Window** following error message coming

[image: Error !!]
when i press OK then MSSQL Server Management Studio closes automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstall/reinstall. You have a corrupt installation here.

Comment: Will Repair Works ?

Comment: You can try. It should

Comment: Will repair take server offline ! Because currently serveries are working correctly !

Comment: You shouldn't be logging in to the SQL server machine to perform any activity with ssms. Client components shouldn't be installed at all on a server machine.

Comment: I have corrupted in server machine :p

Comment: Corrupted what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45402/discussion-between-ragul-and-spaghettidba).

Comment: I disagree regarding client components being installed on servers.  They shouldn't routinely be used on the server, but I install them for emergency usage.

Comment: You have sqlcmd for emergency use